# Tracking clicks on SKOverlay in iOS

Tags: storekit

I'm currently working with SKOverlay in my iOS app and I'm trying to track user clicks on the overlay. I've explored a few solutions but haven't been able to find a reliable method for capturing these clicks. I would appreciate some guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this.

Any advice or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!